# Como saber o nome de uma imagem com JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Escrevi um código no qual ele cria um slide de imagens em uma `div`, gostaria de saber se com Javascript é possível saber o nome da imagem que está passando no slide, pois quando a imagem aparecer, quero que surja um texto descritivo sobre a mesma em uma `div` ao lado.

Pesquisei mas não consegui achar uma maneira de saber o nome da imagem através de Javascript.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto com Javascript, ou terei que usar outro meio de fazer o texto surgir de acordo com a imagem?
Caso tenha que usar outro meio ou  caso vocês conhecam algum melhor, por favor me deem uma ajuda.

Segue o código:

```
#slideShow {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    border:2px solid darkgray;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 2s;
}
div#anterior {
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    transition: 2s;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0px;
}
div#anterior:hover {
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.4;
    font-size:150px;
}
div#proximo {
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    transition: 2s;
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0px;
}
div#proximo:hover {
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.4;
    font-size:150px;
}
```

```
function iniciarSlide() {
    max = 6;
    min = 1;
    fi = min;
    carregarFoto("f1.jpg");
    tr = true;
    document.getElementById("slideShow").addEventListener("transitionend", fimTr)
}
function fimTr() {
    tr = true;
}
function carregarFoto(foto) {
    document.getElementById("slideShow").style.backgroundImage="URL("+foto+")";
}
function prox() {
    if(tr == true) {
        tr = false;
        fi++;
        if (fi > max) {
            fi = min;
        }
        carregarFoto("f"+fi+".jpg");
    }
}
function ant() {
    if (tr = true) {
        tr = false;
        fi--;
        if (fi < min) {
            fi = max;
        }
        carregarFoto("f"+fi+".jpg");
    }
}
```

```
<body onload="iniciarSlide()">
    <div id="slideShow">
        <div id="anterior" onclick="ant()"></div>
        <div id="proximo" onclick="prox()"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do jeito que você está fazendo a unica forma de pegar o nome é pelo link mesmo.

Comment: No seu caso eu faria da seguinte forma: carregar um array com o link mais nome e toda vez que selecionar o index carrega o link e o nome para um elemento no HTML, conseguiu entender ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a lógica que descrevi no comentário, segue abaixo um exemplo.

```js
var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
var descr = document.getElementById('descr');

var arrImgs = [
    ['Burguer King', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3a/Burger_King_Logo.svg'],
    ['Mc Donald\'s', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/McDonald%27s_Golden_Arches.svg'],
    ['Coca Cola', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg']];
var index = 0;

function fSlide(id) {
    
 id === 'prox' ? index === arrImgs.length -1 ? '' : index++ : id === 'prev' ? index < 1 ? '' : index-- : '';
    
 slide.setAttribute('src', arrImgs[index][1]);
    descr.innerText = arrImgs[index][0];
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if(e.target.id === 'prev' || e.target.id === 'prox') {
        fSlide(e.target.id);
    }
});

fSlide();
```

```css
div, img {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
span {
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<span id="prev">Anterior</span>
<div><img id="slide"></img><p id="descr"></p></div>
<span id="prox">Proxima</span>
```